# Exclude folder from website build using MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

We use MSBuild to build our solutions through CruiseControl.  We have several assemblies and a website as part of the solution.  Building through VS2008 the build is successful.  However on the build box we get the following error.

```
ASPNETCOMPILER (,):

        errorASPCONFIG: The CodeDom provider type "Microsoft.VJSharp.VJSharpCodeProvider, VJSharpCodeProvider, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" could not be located.
```

The reason for this is that in the scripts folder of the website we have a couple files with the .java extension.  We don't want these files built.  And really we don't need anything in the scripts folder built.

Is there a way to exclude a folder or an extension from being built within a website project?  Or tell MSBuild to follow the same rules VS2008 is using to decide what to compile?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Web Deployment Projects](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459&displaylang=en) for this. In the WDP you can use the ExcludeFromBuild item to exclude those files. For more info see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479568.aspx.

Comment: As of VS2012 Web Deployment Projects are unsupported. https://stackoverflow.com/a/12061065/

Answer (score 1):

You can remove whole folders with Remove attribute of [Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164283.aspx) element ([brief introduction on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb651786%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)).

For example, if you have items defined like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    ...
    <Compile Include="Tests\Test1.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Tests\SubTests\SubTest1.cs" />
    ...
</ItemGroup>
```

and you want to exclude all classes from "Tests" folder, you can define a task at the end of your project:

```
    ...
    <PropertyGroup>
        <CoreCompileDependsOn>$(CoreCompileDependsOn);ExcludeTestsFolder</CoreCompileDependsOn>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="ExcludeTestsFolder">
        <ItemGroup>
            <Compile Remove="Tests\**\*.cs" />
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

It's also a good idea to define such a task in an external file and import it with [Import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92x05xfs.aspx) element ([thorough explanation in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961753/how-to-hide-files-generated-by-custom-tool-in-visual-studio/3074351#3074351)).

Answer (score 0):

Inside the build file will be an item group with the item/s concerned. Just edit the file to exclude that item.

For [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/646dk05y.aspx):

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <Res Include = "Strings.fr.resources" >
            <Culture>fr</Culture>
        </Res>
        <Res Include = "Dialogs.fr.resources" >
            <Culture>fr</Culture>
        </Res>

        <CodeFiles Include="**\*.cs" Exclude="**\generated\*.cs" />
        <CodeFiles Include="..\..\Resources\Constants.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
...
</Project>
```

Edit: Correction to answer comment.

If you have only a sln file, could you create meta msbuild script that moves the files out of the way, calls the  task to build your solution, and then put them back?

Comment: I don't think this works for WebSite projects since there is no project file.  I looked through the sln file for ways to do this with no luck.

Comment: It's for this reason I don't like web site projects and prefer web applications. You could create an msbuild file just for your CI build though?