# MSBuild, custom task to run custom tool to generate classes for linq to sql model?

Tags: c#, msbuild, msbuild-task

I have the following scenario. We use stored procedures to access the database and we use LiNQ 2 SQL to generate the classes or namely we use Unplugged [LINQ to SQL Generator](http://ulinqgen.codeplex.com/) for this. It has been run as a custom tool but diffing the generated classes is a big pain in the neck. We would like to auto generate the classes but exclude it from version control so I set on the task of creating an msbuild task. Found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961753/how-to-hide-files-generated-by-custom-tool-in-visual-studio) and [this post](http://dasz.at/index.php/2010/02/building-a-simple-msbuild-task/) but I can't solve this one by myself. I added some code the task looks like the following:

```
public class GenerateDesignerDC : Task
{
    public ITaskItem[] InputFiles { get; set; }
    public ITaskItem[] OutputFiles { get; set; }

    public override bool Execute()
    {
        var generatedFileNames = new List<string>();
        foreach (var task in InputFiles)
        {

            string inputFileName = task.ItemSpec;
            string outputFileName = Path.ChangeExtension(inputFileName, ".Designer.cs");
            string result;

            // Build code string
            var generator = new ULinqCodeGenerator("CSharp");
            string fileContent;
            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(inputFileName))
            using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                fileContent = rd.ReadToEnd();
            }

            using (var destination = new FileStream(outputFileName, FileMode.Create))
            {
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(generator.BuildCode(inputFileName, fileContent));
                destination.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            generatedFileNames.Add(outputFileName);
        }

        OutputFiles = generatedFileNames.Select(name => new TaskItem(name)).ToArray();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Now I try to add a custom target for this called custom.target

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <CoreCompileDependsOn>$(CoreCompileDependsOn);GenerateToolOutput</CoreCompileDependsOn>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <UsingTask TaskName="BuildTasks.GenerateDesignerDC" AssemblyFile="BuildTasks.dll" />
    <Target Name="GenerateToolOutput" Inputs="@(dbml)" Outputs="@(dbml->'$(IntermediateOutputPath)%(FileName).designer.cs')">
        <GenerateDesignerDC InputFiles="@(dbml)" OutputFiles="@(dbml->'$(IntermediateOutputPath)%(FileName).designer.cs')">
            <Output ItemGroup="Compile" TaskParameter="OutputFiles" />
        </GenerateDesignerDC>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

I also add the necessary ItemGroups to the project file like follows:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <AvailableItemName Include="dbml" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="@(dbml)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And finally I add the files to the project with the following:

```
<dbml Include="DAL\SettingsDC.dbml">
    <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    <Generator>ULinqToSQLGenerator</Generator>
    <LastGenOutput>SettingsDC.designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
</dbml>
```

This causes an error message saying

> The "GenerateDesignerDC" task has an
>   invalid output specification. The
>   "TaskParameter" attribute is required,
>   and either the "ItemName" or
>   "PropertyName" attribute must be
>   specified (but not both).

What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You haven't declared an output property in your task. You have to use the `Output` attribute on `OutputFiles` property.

```
public class GenerateDesignerDC : Task
{
    [Required]
    public ITaskItem[] InputFiles { get; set; }

    [Output]
    public ITaskItem[] OutputFiles { get; set; }

    public override bool Execute()
    {
        var generatedFileNames = new List<string>();
        foreach (var task in InputFiles)
        {

            string inputFileName = task.ItemSpec;
            string outputFileName = Path.ChangeExtension(inputFileName, ".Designer.cs");
            string result;

            // Build code string
            var generator = new ULinqCodeGenerator("CSharp");
            string fileContent;
            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(inputFileName))
            using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                fileContent = rd.ReadToEnd();
            }

            using (var destination = new FileStream(outputFileName, FileMode.Create))
            {
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(generator.BuildCode(inputFileName, fileContent));
                destination.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            generatedFileNames.Add(outputFileName);
        }

        OutputFiles = generatedFileNames.Select(name => new TaskItem(name)).ToArray();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct, I also needed to add <Output TaskParameter="OutputFiles" Propertyname="OutputFiles" />