# Reading msbuild syntax

Tags: c#, msbuild, msbuild-task

I've run across msbuild syntax that I don't understand. The following snippet is from [another question about making a custom msbuild task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187666/msbuild-custom-task-to-run-custom-tool-to-generate-classes-for-linq-to-sql-mode)

```
<GenerateDesignerDC
  InputFiles="@(dbml)"
  OutputFiles="@(dbml->'$(IntermediateOutputPath)%(FileName).designer.cs')">
    ...
```

What does `@(dbml->'$(IntermediateOutputPath)%(FileName).designer.cs')` mean? The `@` sign usually references the files in an [`ItemGroup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/646dk05y.aspx); what does the `->` arrow inside an `@(...)` mean?

What is this little language (with the `@`s, `$`s, `%`s, `->`, etc.)  used for substitutions into the attributes of build tasks called?

Comment: The [documentation I have found](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx) suggests that there's much more to this little language than I've seen before. Where is this stuff concisely documented?

Comment: The [`Condition` syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szfhaft.aspx) is related, at least for strings, and has documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This specific syntax is called a [transform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171476.aspx).

> A transform is a one-to-one conversion of one item list to another. In addition to enabling a project to convert item lists, a transform enables a target to identify a direct mapping between its inputs and outputs.

The syntax isn't explicitly documented. The part before the `->` is an [item list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383819.aspx) like that which would normally be referenced by `@`. In the example `@(dbml->...)` it is transforming the `dbml` item list. The part after the `->` is an expression for the new file name. It can refer to any [item metadata](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171453.aspx#BKMK_ItemMetadata) with a `%` symbol. In the example it's constructing a string with the `$(IntermediateOutputPath)` property and the `%(Filename)` [well-known item metadata](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383819.aspx).

The well-known item metadata should be available for any item and includes most notably the path to the item

```
MetaData        Example     
%(FullPath)     C:\MyProject\Source\Program.cs
%(RootDir)      C:\
%(Directory)       MyProject\Source\
%(Filename)                         Program
%(Extension)                               .cs
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if these little language has a special name. From what I know these are ways defined to extract or display values of items or metadata that items may contain.

For eg: `@` symbol is used the get the value of any ItemType.
For item list transformations `@(SourceFiles -> '%(Filename).obj')` is used.

Check out this link for more information
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393573.aspx

See the sections from Examining Item Type Values.

Comment: The linked documentation is precisely the concise documentation that I wish I'd found.

Comment: I am glad I could be of help :)